# How should i support chrome functionality in Android webview?

Tags: android

I want to use chrome functionality in my android old webview with some limitation like video chatting. but when i open that link on chrome then open camera option and work fine.But for older version of android default browser or webview not work for me.

If anyone have any idea tell me.

Comment: This link will suggest u about the webview in Chrome [link](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview)

Comment: I find and check this but not help much more and i found one link for chromeview [link](http://geekonjava.blogspot.in/2014/08/chromium-webview-custom-android-webview.html)